# Facebook API Likes Not Accurate?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Checking to see if anyone here can help - I have a bunch of users on my site having this problem..

Testing my own account after getting failure issues from several of my website's members, I discovered that Likes are not being recorded accurately to my profile. While logged in, I liked a page (this is just an example, the same problem happens on multiple pages). It was:

http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1869946/

If I look this page up with FQL or on the Graph API Explorer, I can find the ID for this is:

10150237928985504

If I look at my list of Likes, by going to graph.facebook.com/me/likes it does not show up.

When I enter this in the Graph API Explorer:

me/likes/10150237928985504

I get:

```
{
"data": [
]
}
```

HOWEVER - if I go to my Facebook Profile I can see the Like there. The page has been added to my news feed and the link shows up in my list of Likes.

So why is the fact that I Liked the page not available via the Graph API or FQL?

Thanks very much!